# Работа с классом QTabWidget , размещение вкладок

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qtabwidget, qtabbar

Есть панель со вкладками (их всего три), как сделать чтобы вкладка номер **`3`** было сверху как вот здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен.

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setWindowTitle("Класс QTabWidget")
window.resize(400, 150)

tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
tab.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое вкладки 1"),
           "Вкладка 1")
tab.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое вкладки 2"),
           "Вкладка 2")
tab.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel("Содержимое вкладки 3"),
           "Вкладка 3")
tab.setElideMode(QtCore.Qt.ElideLeft)
tab.setCurrentIndex(0)

vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(tab)
window.setLayout(vbox)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вкладок 5, но они размещены в двух рядах? Или вкладок 2, и при выборе одной из них, в ней еще 3 вкладки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class TabBar(QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        size = QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        w = int(self.width()/self.count())
        return QSize(w, size.height())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tabwidget = QTabWidget()
        self.tabwidget.setTabBar(TabBar())
        self.tabwidget.setMovable(True)
        self.tabwidget.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabwidget.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        self.tabwidget.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabwidget)
        for name in ("Имя компьютера", "Оборудование"):
            self.create_widgets(name)

    def create_widgets(self, name):
        w = QMainWindow()
        self.tabwidget.addTab(w, name)
        tab = QTabWidget()
        tab.setTabBar(TabBar())  
        tab.setMovable(True)
        tab.setDocumentMode(True)
        tab.setElideMode(Qt.ElideRight)
        tab.setUsesScrollButtons(True)
        w.setCentralWidget(tab)
        for i in ["Дополнительно", "Защита системы", "Удаленный доступ"]:      # range(5):
            tab.addTab(QWidget(), "{}".format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(700, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Nick а как сделать так например ты выбрал верхнюю вкладку и он эа отобразилась снизу тоесть 2 ряд (верхний) стал нижним , а в 1 ряд (нижний) стал верхним и так меняются по мере открытия вкладок

Comment: @AleksandrSilkin вы просили сделать размещение вкладок как на изображении. Я вам показал вариант как это можно сделать. Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте их, сформировав новый вопрос.